# Get access to fusion tables

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'd like to show some map layer on my webpage, so I decided to give a try to this Google service. As the data is collected in a database in my server, I chose to use a service account as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#service_accounts) and then use the private key generated in my php script.

Everything works fine when creating a table and inserting some test values. I get the table Id and I'm able to play with it from my script. The problem is that I don't know how to access these table from the web browser. In my API console usage stats are shown fine, but when logging with my account to Google Drive I don't see any table in there.

Where am I supposed to access them if at all possible? Do either the apps.googleusercontent.com or developer.gserviceaccount.com accounts play any role to log into some other service to get access through web?

I also got an api key associated, but when trying to query a table I get a 401 error.

Any hint? I'm feeling a bit lost now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a *Service Account* right?
So when you create a table with this account, this account will be the table owner. No one else has permission to see this table.

When you access the Fusion Tables web interface with *Your Personal Account*, you will only see tables that you createdwith your Personal Account.

If you wish to inspect the tables created with your Service Account, you have to use the Google Drive API with your Service Account credentials to give access permission to your Personal Account. 
Also if you wish to make your table (or any other type of document) public, you need to use this Google Drive API again.
See more about the topic here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

**Tip**: if you want to achieve something on behalf of your Service Account that you only need once (so no need to implement a logic for it in your webapp) I'd seriously advise you to consider using the [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). You can set your Service Account credentials in the "Settings" and issue authorized requests on behalf of your Service Account. Very usefull tool, no coding needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is starting to look a bit complicated. What I want to achieve is very simple: feed a fusion table with data from a server php script, and then show any user visiting my web page a map showing this data. Does such a simple use case take all these steps? I'd like to avoid any over-complication if at all possible.

Comment: You said, that you had already populated a fusion table from php using a service account . You're through the worst part, don't give up in the finish. You most probably used the google-php-api-client, right? If so, you already have to have a Google_Client $client in your script. Use this to get your hands on the Drive API permission service: $permissionsService=new Google_DriveService($client)->permissions;

Comment: Once you have it, create a new Permission, that will make your table public to anyone like this:
$permission = new Google_Permission();
$permission->setRole('reader');
$permission->setType('anyone');
Then add this permission to your fusion table: 
$permissionsService->insert($tableId, $permission);
That's it, you're done. From now, your table is readable(but for everyone, not just you) and public. Now you can put it on a Google Maps "Fusion Layer".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patiente. I wasn't going to give up, as I need to get this done :) But as said before I wondered if a simple approach wasn't available, just to be sure, as I'm a newbie to google apis. I'm not saying this is complicated but would have prefered a simple method in the fusiontable client api to set the table's privacy, instead of having to rely on a separate api just for this. Your help allowed me to move forward so thanks a lot. Now I need to find out other issues but the basics at least are working.

Comment: Since Fusion Tables is integrated to Google Drive it is just another document type for it. Google could have integrated the permission service to the Fusion Tables API too, but it would then break several rules of SaaS and REST concepts. In short: you just have to live with it..